# What happened to my old account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I used to use Stack Exchange a lot with an email-based login, but I haven't been active for a couple years. When I came here just now I had an Inbox with messages, and the trophy icon showed me a list of my achievements. So the site obviously knows who I am. But when I tried to join this community, it asked me to create a new account using my Google id. Why couldn't I join as-is? Is there a way to do that, or associate this new account with my old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I tried to join this community, it asked me to create a new account using my Google id.

Besides that you seem to use your old account and are logged in to post this question, I am not a 100% sure what you are talking about.

This is what I see when joining a new community:

[image]

I am logged in with Google automatically with my browser (Chrome).

Were you asked to create a Google ID additionally?

> Is there a way to do that, or associate this new account with my old one?

As the picture above clearly states

> > We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.

And this is what apparently has happened already. If I check your profile here, I see this:

[image]

Going to your Stack Overflow account profile, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, apparently I was just confused about how the Stack multiverse works.